# Cocoa frameworks that don't need to be #imported

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

I noticed that after adding certain frameworks to a project in Xcode, you don't have to import any of its header files in order to access its classes. How come those classes are "magically" available without the import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for `yourProjectName-Prefix.pch` file. There you'll find:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Inside the `#ifdef` statement you can add any files you like that will automatically imported throughout you whole project.